# Dynamic assignment in Nolio

Tags: devops, nolio

I am working with Nolio automation Studio & need command to find out how many dynamic servers are assigned to a nolio agent & also to list them through command line. I dont have admin rights to the studio but have access to nolio agent server.

Comment: Can you please share some additional information or supply screen shots to explain your question? Do you have more than one Nolio agent installed on the same server?